# Unable to delete from MySQL table where in set

Tags: mysql, sql

The first query provides the set of ids that should be deleted.  The second query tries to delete them.

```
select abstracts.pmid from abstracts where abstracts.pmid not in 
(select pmid from erpubtbl);

//Fine 555,556,...

delete from abstracts where (pmid) IN (
    select abstracts.pmid from abstracts where abstracts.pmid not in 
    (select pmid from erpubtbl)
);

//You can't specify target table 'abstracts' for update in FROM clause
```

Why can't you specify the target table like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `delete` from a `table` and **reference** the same table in a `subquery`.

May be this trick should help you

```
DELETE FROM abstracts
WHERE  ( pmid ) IN (SELECT *
                    FROM   (SELECT abstracts.pmid
                            FROM   abstracts
                            WHERE  abstracts.pmid NOT IN (SELECT pmid
                                                          FROM   erpubtbl))a);
```

Or even `Inner Join`

```
DELETE FROM abstracts
USING abstracts
INNER JOIN (SELECT abstracts.pmid
            FROM   abstracts
            WHERE  abstracts.pmid NOT IN (SELECT pmid
                                          FROM   erpubtbl) 
            ) b
         ON abstracts.pmid = b.pmid
```

Comment: Your first query returns 'Every derived table must have its own alias' The second query worked!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this in MySQL is with a `join`:

```
delete a
    from abstracts a join
         (select a2.pmid
          from abstracts a2
          where a2.pmid not in (select pmid from erpubtbl)
         ) aa
         on a.pmid = aa.pmid;
```

However, I think this is simpler without mentioning the `abstracts` table twice:

```
delete a
    from abstracts a left join
         erpubtbl e
         on a.pmid = e.pmid
    where e.pmid is null;
```

This will delete the rows in `abstracts` that have a `pmid` that is not in `erpubtbl` -- which is how I am reading your original query.

Comment: The first query worked, but the second query seems to just spin.  Thanks.

Comment: @4m1r . . . That is interesting.  I can't think of how the second one would hang unless there are locks on the table.  But glad the first one worked.